# Casting return type from interface

Tags: java

I am making LRUcache app. 
I've got an interface. I cannot change it. It implements methods and I don't know how to return that cache instead of interface type.

In method getItem() instead of returning specific value I can only return whole map.

```
public class LRUCache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> implements Cache View{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int limiter;
private LRUCache<String, Object> lruInst;



private LRUCache(int size) {
    super(size, 0.75f, true);
    this.limiter = size;
}


@Override
protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
    return size() > limiter;
}

public static<String,Object> LRUCache<String,Object> newInstance(int size) {
    return new LRUCache<>(size);
}
@Override
    public CacheItem getItem(int index) {

    List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>(lruInst.keySet());
    for (int i = 0; i < lruInst.size(); i++) {
        String key = keyList.get(i);
        Object value = lruInst.get(key);
        if (i == index) {
            System.out.println("z indexu "+value);
            return lruInst;
        }
    }
    return null;
}//this does not work, it return only Map

@Override
public CacheItem getItem(String key) {
    String aa = lruInst.get(key).toString();

    System.out.println(aa);

    return  (CacheItem) lruInst.getValue();
}//this does not work



public interface CacheView {


CacheItem getItem(int index);

CacheItem getItem(String key);
```

Comment: the issue  you are facing is  not  clear?

Comment: LRUCache extends from a LinkedHashMap then why is necessary to create a LRUCache as private member of itself?

Comment: We code to an interface so that the implementing code does exactly what the interface expects of it. So I think in your case it will always return Cache Item instead of the value you have been expecting. Instead the return type of the method getItem should have been V getItem(int index)